# Rails Ajax completed 200 OK but record doesn't get updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to Rails and am trying to update a "milestone" item in my app using AJAX. Milestones belong to Projects. I've been able to successfully implement AJAX requests for creating and deleting, but am running into issues here with updating.

When I submit a form, it says it was processed by MilestonesController#update as JS, with status of Completed 200 OK, and create.js.erb runs, but the milestone does not actually get updated.

Here are the relevant files, let me know if I can provide any additional context and thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

From terminal, after checking a checkbox to update completed to be true:

```
Started PATCH "/projects/clustertruck-branding-design-and-development/milestones/24" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-31 16:12:04 -0500
Processing by MilestonesController#update as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "milestone"=>{"project_id"=>"7", "completed"=>"true", "completed_date"=>"2015-12-31"}, "commit"=>"✓", "project_id"=>"clustertruck-branding-design-and-development", "id"=>"24"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."slug" = 'clustertruck-branding-design-and-development'  ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Milestone Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "milestones".* FROM "milestones"  WHERE "milestones"."project_id" = ? AND "milestones"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 7], ["id", 24]]
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 24], ["taggable_type", "Milestone"]]
  Rendered milestones/_milestone.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered milestones/update.js.erb (11.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 14.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

routes.rb

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'milestones#index', as: :tag

root :to => "projects#index"
resources :memberships
resources :projects do
  resources :milestones
end
```

update.js.erb

```
<% if @milestone.valid? %>
    $('li#milestone-<%= @milestone.id %>').first().after("<%= j render @milestone %>");
    $('li#milestone-<%= @milestone.id %>').first().remove();
    $('li#month-marker-<%= @milestone.id %>').hide();
    $('li#month-marker-<%= @milestone.id %>').first().show();
    $(".modal").modal("hide");
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
<% else %>
    alert("<%= @milestone.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% end %>
```

milestones_controller.rb
    class MilestonesController < ApplicationController

```
  before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action :require_editor, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :load_project
  before_filter :load_milestone, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @milestones = Milestone.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def new
    @milestone = Milestone.new
  end

  def create
    @milestone = Milestone.new(milestone_params)
    @milestone.save
  end

  def destroy
    @milestone.destroy
  end

  private
    def milestone_params
      params.require(:milestone).permit(:name, :description, :completed, :date, :completed, :completed_date, :project_id, :tag_list)
    end

    def load_project
      @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def load_milestone
      @milestone = @project.milestones.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

_milestone.html.erb

```
<% if @monthmarker != milestone.date.strftime("%B") %>
  <% @monthmarker = milestone.date.strftime("%B") %>
  <li class="month-marker" id="month-marker-<%= milestone.id %>"><%= @monthmarker %></li>
<% end %>

<% completion_classes = ""
completion_classes << " complete" if milestone.milestone_complete?
completion_classes << " incomplete" if milestone.milestone_incomplete?
completion_classes << " overdue" if milestone.milestone_overdue?
%>
<li id="milestone-<%= milestone.id %>" class="card timeline-card<%= completion_classes %>">
  <div class="assignment-bubble">
    <% if milestone %>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="card-header">
    <% if current_user && current_user.editor? %>
      <a href="#" class="card-header-edit-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-milestone-modal-<%= milestone.id %>">Edit</a>
    <% end %>
    <% if milestone.date.present? && !milestone.completed %>
      Due: <%= milestone.date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y") %>
    <% end %>
    <% if milestone.completed && milestone.completed_date.present? %>
      Completed: <%= milestone.completed_date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <% if current_user && current_user.editor? %>
      <% if milestone.completed %>
        <%= form_for [milestone.project,milestone], :remote => true do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id) %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:completed, value: false) %>
          <%= f.submit "✓", :class => "status-checkbox #{completion_classes} mark-complete" %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= form_for [milestone.project,milestone], :remote => true do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id) %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:completed, value: true) %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:completed_date, value: Date.current) %>
          <%= f.submit "✓", :class => "status-checkbox #{completion_classes} mark-complete" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <div class="status-checkbox view-only-status<%= completion_classes %>">✓</div>
    <% end %>
    <h3 class="name"><%= milestone.name %></h3>
    <p class="description"><%= milestone.description %></p>
    <% if milestone.tag_list.present? %>
      <ul class="tags">
        <li class="tag"><%= raw milestone.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join('</li><li class="tag">') %></li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="edit-milestone-modal-<%= milestone.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="milestoneModalLabel">
    <%= form_for [milestone.project,milestone], :remote => true do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="milestoneModalLabel">Edit Milestone</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
              <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :milestone %>
              <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :description %>
              <%= f.text_area :description, :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :date %>
              <%= f.date_field :date, "data-format" => "MM/dd/yyyy", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :completed %>
              <%= f.select :completed, options_for_select([['Incomplete' ,''], ['Complete', true]], milestone.completed), :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :completed_date %>
              <%= f.date_field :completed_date, "data-format" => "MM/dd/yyyy" %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %>
              <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <% if current_user && current_user.editor? %>
              <%= link_to [milestone.project,milestone], method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this milestone?' }, :class => "btn btn-delete", :remote => true do %>Delete Milestone<% end %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.submit "Save Milestone", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</li>
```

Comment: but... there's no code in your `update` method? How do you expect the record to be updated?

Comment: looks like you have not implemented the update action _and_ do not call it. probably you call create twice on the same milestone, what does the logfile for your environment say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your update method to the following:

```
def update
  @milestone.update_attributes(milestone_params)
end
```

Right now your update method has no logic, so it's showing fine and loading your milestones/editors but nothing is actually going on.

You should also look to expand it in the future like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @milestone.update_attributes(milestone_params)
    format.js   {} #this simply display your javascript
  else
    # Insert some kind of logic here where it displays errors
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre! That's exactly what it was. Appreciate the help!